# Ubuntu Touch - Notifications not showing

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email, notification

Email notifications are not appearing in my top bar. I have all my telegram notifications appearing all OK. I have the email notifications set to on in my settings but they are still not showing. I have the bq E5 and the M10 tablet running the latest version, that are not showing the email notifications. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: The same for me at Nexus 4. I never have had any email notification by dekko. I thought they are not supported!?

Comment: Well I just have taken a look to the noyification section in the Systemsettings. Well yes, Dekko is listed there and it is enabled. Does anybody else receive notifications by dekko?

Comment: I also have Proton Mail and I have stopped receiving notifications for that too.